# Relative time/space - Two clock thought experiment

Tags: special-relativity

Please pardon my english.

Here is my simple thought experiment.

```
In universe, there are two clocks A, B.
B moved outward at the speed of light for 1 second at 00:00"
```

From clock A, I think it will say "00:01" and clock B will say "00:00". But, if the motion is relative, from clock B, the clock A probably moved outward at the speed of light so that after 1 second, clock B would say "00:01" and clock A would say "00:00". This contradicts the first guess.

I am sure I misunderstood the theory. Could someone help on this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it was possible duplicate but the answers are focused on muons which I don't know much about and they seem too difficult to follow. I will try to understand from that answer but still hope that someone can explain the basics of relativity in the given context.

Comment: You were doing fine, until you said there was a contradiction. A sees B's clock running slow; B sees A's clock running slow. You just need to give up on the idea that one of those statements is wrong.

Comment: JohnRennie's answer covers the reason why he discusses the muon in place of the clocks in his answer. Nathaniel's answer, however, sticks with clocks.

Comment: @richardb What you're saying is that both are correct. Then after 1 second, what time A and B would say? or is it irrelevant as time is relative? I feel that I am getting closer..

Comment: @KyleKanos The explanation of Nathaniel is too short for me. I hope the possible answer of this question may help many understand the basics of relativity.